"See", "visit", "rerer to" before a hyperlink

To convert from Markdown to PDF using Pandoc:

Install pdflatex:
brew install basictex

For other options, visit https://superuser.com/q/1038612.

Recommended: Relaunch the terminal.

Convert from Markdown to PDF:
pandoc input.md -o output.pdf




What is the correct word to use before a link? "See", "visit", "refer to"?

They're all fine, as would be go to and other alternatives,, or nothing at all. Or for the purposes of a web page, you could have the text "Click here for more options", and make the word here be a hot link to the specified address.

Thanks! But what you mean by "nothing at all" here?

Just "For other options: " would be perfectly natural for a web page.

You might get more useful feedback from User Experience Stack Exchange
